# LibreSSL syscall error

Tags: macos, ssl

I’ve got a MacBook Pro running Catalina 10.15.6.  I started it up this morning and noticed that Safari “failed to establish a secure connection” with any site I attempted to visit.  I’m connected to my apartment’s Wi-Fi and my other devices on the network are working fine.

On the terminal, I ran

```
curl -v https://www.amazon.com
```

This produced

```
Trying 23.32.59.78
TCP_NODERELAY set
Connected to www.amazon.com (23.32.69.78) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
successfully set certificate verify locations:
    CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
    CApath: None
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.amazon.com:443
Closing connection 0
```

I’ve restarted my computer, ran diagnostics, connected to a different network, and even reinstalled the OS.  Nothing has changed.

What’s interesting is that it works when booting in safe mode.

I have no antivirus or VPN software.

LibreSSL’s version is 2.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Covenant Eyes, a program I have running on my computer which has some VPN-like features, was the problem.  I'm still not sure what the issue was but uninstalling it fixed everything.  Reinstalling it did not recreate the problem.